# multiple waves in wavesurfer with for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

i am trying to generate multiple wavesurfer audio waves using an for loop, this is my code:

```
        $.ajax({
        url: "./php/getMusic.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            var wavesurfer = []
            var array = data;
            console.log(array)
            var i = 0;
            while( i < array.length){
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

                    document.getElementById("trackholder").innerHTML += '<div id="wave'+i+'" class="waveform"><div class="tracklogo">Sample logo</div><div class="title"><p><font color="lightblue" size="5em">Sample artist -<font size="4em">Sample Title</p></div></font></font></div></div>'

                    wavesurfer[i] = Object.create(WaveSurfer);

                    wavesurfer[i].init({
                        container: document.getElementById("wave"+i),
                        waveColor: 'purple',
                        progressColor: 'blue'
                    });

                    wavesurfer[i].load("./music/"+array[i]);

                    console.log(i+" is loading")
                  })
            i++
        }
    }
})
```

the problem is with the `DOMCOntentLoaded` event listener, with it none of the waves will load and without it only on will load.

note: the array called `'array'` contains 2 elements: `demo1.mp3` and `demo2.mp3`

Comment: Have you tried putting the while loop within the DOMContentLoaded event handler instead of outside it?

Comment: that doesn't work, the result is the same as no event handler

Comment: I don't think you should need the DOM listener and definitely shouldn't call it for each array element. Can you post the HTML that is produced when only one loads (ie: without DOMContentLoaded listener)?